# Displaying console feed from game server on rcon client

Tags: java, source-engine

I'm writing an RCON client for an Insurgency (Source engine game) dedicated server. I'm using the [RCON protocol](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_RCON_Protocol) defined by Valve that is used in all of the games that use the Source engine. I can successfully send commands to the server, and display the server's response to those commands. However, I have no idea how to read or request the feed displayed by the in-game console (which contains the part I'm primarily interested in: the killfeed). I have looked at querying the server for a possible request to be sent the feed, but there is no such functionality listed.

How would I go about retrieving the console feed from the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***You cannot request the console feed from the server via RCON.***

---

Two alternative solutions come to mind:

#### Save the output of the server application

Insurgency (or most source servers for that matter) prints the information you are looking for to ***stdout***. The most elegant solution to save this output would be to start the server via *systemd* and read it from the *syslog* via *journalctl*.

*As a more simple solution you can just write it to a file using a pipe:*

```
./start_server.sh > output.log
```

*Or if you still want to see the output as it is printed:*

```
./start_server.sh | tee output.log
```

---

#### Use sourcemod

You can write a [sourcemod](https://www.sourcemod.net/)-plugin, or use an existing one that records and provides those information. The *[SuperLogs](https://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?t=99231)* plugin comes to mind, but I haven't used it in a long time. This will be significantly more work.

---

I have been using the first solution for a long time now. Be aware that Insurgency *buffers the output* and only writes it once that buffer is full, leading to delays of *20 minutes and upwards*. This can be improved by setting `sv_logflush  1` in the Insurgency config.